# jQuery list filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a list of JSON objects populating and I'm trying to get the filters I've placed at the top working: http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/vxpMRJ

As you can see, I've come up with a clunky spaghetti method that uses this code:

```
  $('input[name="newGuitars"]').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('.vdListing').each(function(){
      var dng1 = $(this).find('.dNG').last()
      var dng = dng1.text()
      if (dng == '') {$(this).hide()}
                })
    }
              if (!this.checked) {
      $('.vdListing').each(function(){
      var dng1 = $(this).find('.dNG').last()
      var dng = dng1.text()
      if (dng == '') {$(this).show()}
                })
    }

});
```

I used that on the new guitars and used guitars checkboxes and realized that (aside from being a stupid method) my filters would hide/show elements without regard for the other filter conditions.

I'm just looking for a better way to go about doing this, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) - it makes building data-driven interfaces like this massively simpler, with much cleaner code.  If you are interested then I can quickly make a codePen to demonstrate with your data.

Comment: I thought about using angular, but I'm terrible at it and I've never used react before. I'd like to see it in react, but I can't guarantee I'll be able to manipulate it myself afterward because I suck

Comment: I'll make something this evening for you.  I hated Angular when I tried it and found it extremely non-intuitive, but found React to be the opposite.

Comment: OK but only if it's not an issue for you, I don't want to bother anyone with my stupid projects. Maybe I'll end up using the language though, I have been making JSON databases a lot lately

Comment: [CodePen here](http://codepen.io/alsiola/pen/gmKYxX) Unstyled and only with new/used guitar filters, but hopefully it will give you an idea of how this could be implemented in React.  Feel free to ask if you have any questions.  If you do decide to go down the React rabbithole then the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html) are a good place to start, and the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) project is superb for getting up and running quickly.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is how I'd prefer to learn things rather than from scratch, to have a working model that I can learn from to expand on - I'm going to spend some time on it today, hopefully I can pick it up quickly.

Comment: I suck http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/XMYoBB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138971/discussion-between-alex-young-and-joel).

Answer (score 1):

I only find a solution from the old answer in StackOverflow.

Hope it helpful.

I custom for your case.

This method is best way to filter instead of using your way.

Because your current approach isn't very dynamic, selectors and arrays are being hardcoded, so each time you add new filter options you'll have to add code to handle it.

Instead, just bind a change handler to all filter checkboxes, you can collect up their values, and group them by their respective names, eg:

```
var $filterCheckboxes = $( 'input[name="newGuitars"]' );

$filterCheckboxes.on( 'change', function() {

    var selectedFilters = {};

    $filterCheckboxes.filter( ':checked' ).each( function() {

    if ( ! selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty( this.name ) ) {
        selectedFilters[ this.name ] = [];
    }

    selectedFilters[ this.name ].push( this.value );

    } );

} );
```

This will create an object containing `input-name -> value` array pairs, eg:

```
selectedFilters = {
  'fl-colour': [ 'red', 'green' ],
  'fl-size': [ 'tiny' ]
};
```

You can then loop over each `selectedFilters`, and filter your `.dNG` elements. If a `.dNG` element matches a value in each named set, we return true so that the element is included in the `$filteredResults` collection:

```
// create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
var $filteredResults = $( '.dNG' );

// loop over the selected filter name -> (array) values pairs
$.each( selectedFilters, function( name, filterValues ) {

  // filter each .dNG element
  $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter( function() {

    var matched = false,
        currentFilterValues = $( this ).data( 'category' ).split( ' ' );

    // loop over each category value in the current .dNG's data-category
    $.each( currentFilterValues, function( _, currentFilterValue ) {

      // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
      // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
      // set of filters, we only need to match once

      if ( $.inArray( currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1 ) {
        matched = true;
        return false;
      }

    } );    

    // if matched is true the current .dNG element is returned
    return matched;    

  } );

} );
```

Then simply hide all the `.dNG` elements, and show the `$filteredResults`, eg:

```
$( '.dNG' ).hide().filter( $filteredResults ).show();
```

You can see [jsfiddle at here.](http://jsfiddle.net/n3EmN/171/)

Comment: I think..maybe I understand what's going on here, but not enough to get this working for my own stuff. My info is being brought in through a JSON file, so I'd have to make each of the .dvListing divs have a data-category with all their properties in it. I'll try to get this working though

Comment: Well, I just spent a lot of time working this into my code and it still screws up when it comes to working with multiple filters being turned on and off. I put the new one here: http://codepen.io/JTBennett/pen/YZvzOR